# How to use $lookup and $in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> Colleges

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42b5c65b41027845938ae"),
    "clgID" : "100",
    "name" : "Vivekananda"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42b5c65b41027845938ad"),
    "clgID" : "200",
    "name" : "National"
}
```

Point : 1 => Take all `clgID` From Colleges collection.

> Subjects:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42c2465b41027845938b0"),
    "name" : "Hindi",
    "members" : {
        "student" : [
            "123"
        ]
    },
    "college" : {
        "collegeID" : "100"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd42c2465b41027845938af"),
    "name" : "English",
    "members" : {
        "student" : [
            "456",
            "789"
        ]
    },
    "college" : {
        "collegeID" : "100"
    }
}
```

Point : 2 => `Subjects` collection we are mapped `clgID` under `college.collegeID`, Subjects collection we need to take the values of `members.student` based on `clgID`.

> CollegeProducts

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "StudentProdcutID" : "123",
    "StudentID" : "FF80",
    "CID" : "Facebook"
},
{
    "_id" : "456",
    "StudentProdcutID" : "456",
    "StudentID" : "FF81",
    "CID" : "Facebook"
},
{
    "_id" : "789",
    "StudentProdcutID" : "789",
    "StudentID" : "FF82",
    "CID" : "Facebook"
}
```

Point : 3 => `CollegeProducts` collection we are mapped `members.student` values under `StudentProdcutID`, CollegeProducts collection we need to take the values in `StudentID`. `CollegeProducts` collection we need to check condition `CID` should be `Facebook` and take the values of `StudentID` based on `members.student`.

> UserDetails

```
{
    "name" : "A",
    "StudentID" : "FF80"

},
{
    "name" : "B",
    "StudentID" : "FF81"
},
{
    "name" : "C",
    "StudentID" : "FF82"
}
```

Point : 3 => `UserDetails` collection we are mapped `StudentID` values under `StudentID`, UserDetails collection we need to take the values of `name`.

> Expected Output:

```
{
"collegeName" : "National",
"StudentName" : "A"
},
{
"collegeName" : "National",
"StudentName" : "B"
},
{
"collegeName" : "National",
"StudentName" : "C"
}
```

> My Code

```
 db.Colleges.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "clgID": { "$in": ["100", "200"] }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Subjects",
    "localField": "clgID",
    "foreignField": "college.collegeID",
    "as": "clg"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$clg", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "clgId": "$clg.college.collegeID", "_id": "$_id" },
    "groupDetails": { "$push": "$clg.members.student" },
    "clgName": { "$first": "$name" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "clgName": 1,
    "groupDetails": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$groupDetails",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

I am not getting my expected output,kindly help me anyone. i am using **mongodb version3.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother grouping if you want the the each output to be one user, you're just doing double the work.

Change your query to this:

```
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "clgID" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "100", 
                    "200"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "Subjects", 
            "localField" : "clgID", 
            "foreignField" : "college.collegeID", 
            "as" : "clg"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$clg", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$clg.members.student", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "collegeName" : "$name", 
            "student" : "$clg.members.student"
        }
    }
],
```

Now with the second unwind each object contains the college name and -ONE- student so all we need to do now is project in the required form.

EDIT: full query according to request

```
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "clgID" : {
                "$in" : [
                    "100", 
                    "200"
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "Subjects", 
            "localField" : "clgID", 
            "foreignField" : "college.collegeID", 
            "as" : "clg"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$clg", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$clg.members.student", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "CollegeProducts", 
            "localField" : "clg.members.student", 
            "foreignField" : "StudentProdcutID", 
            "as" : "clgproduct"
        }
    }, 
    {   // can skip this unwind if theres always only one match.
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$clgproduct", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$match" : {
            "clgproduct.CID" : "Facebook"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$lookup" : {
            "from" : "UserDetails", 
            "localField" : "clgproduct.StudentID", 
            "foreignField" : "StudentID", 
            "as" : "student"
        }
    }, 
    {   // can skip this unwind if theres always only one user matched.
        "$unwind" : {
            "path" : "$student", 
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : true
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "collegeName" : "$name", 
            "student" : "$student.name"
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, but I want to add one condition is collegeProducts collection CID it should be a Facebook, in this code where I have to add that condition?

Comment: you need to add another lookup before the project, then match on the type.

Comment: Can you please update your answer, and also student name we have to take userDetails this part also not there in ur code .

Comment: @ Mr. tom slabbaert, your are getting my question means can you please update your answer

Comment: i think i understood what you meant, i edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.Colleges.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "clgID": { "$in": ["100", "200"] }}},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Subjects",
    "localField": "clgID",
    "foreignField": "college.collegeID",
    "as": "clg"
  }},
  { "$unwind": { "path": "$clg", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "clgId": "$clg.college.collegeID", "_id": "$_id" },
    "groupDetails": { "$push": "$clg.members.student" },
    "clgName": { "$first": "$name" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "clgName": 1,
    "groupDetails": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$groupDetails",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$this", "$$value"] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "CollegeProduct",
    "localField": "groupDetails",
    "foreignField": "StudentProdcutID",
    "as": "CollegeProduct"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$CollegeProduct" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "UserDetails",
    "localField": "CollegeProduct.StudentID",
    "foreignField": "StudentID",
    "as": "Student"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Student" },
  { "$project": { "collegeName": "clgName", "StudentName": "$Student.name" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LFPzMWhG1Qx)

[**`Output`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LFPzMWhG1Qx)

```
[
  {
    "StudentName": "A",
    "_id": ObjectId("5cd42b5c65b41027845938ae"),
    "collegeName": "clgName"
  },
  {
    "StudentName": "B",
    "_id": ObjectId("5cd42b5c65b41027845938ae"),
    "collegeName": "clgName"
  },
  {
    "StudentName": "C",
    "_id": ObjectId("5cd42b5c65b41027845938ae"),
    "collegeName": "clgName"
  }
]
```

Comment: Possibly you are not using the correct collection name in `from` part.

Comment: Just I have copied your code and run in my system, I didn’t change anything

Comment: That's what I am saying. You need to change the `from` part in the answer because your collection may be of different names.

Comment: Yes,  column names only mismatched, I collegeProduct and userDetails lookup from field is mismatched. Can you please update your code based on my columns names. Because I am getting confused